# VSFTPD : FTP can't resolve routing

Tags: routing, ftp

I'm setting up a server but I can't get FTP to work properly. I use CentOS with vsftpd as ftp server. I'm working on a virtual server and there seems to be an error with the routing. When trying to log with FileZilla, this shows up and the connection fails :

227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,21,102,251)

192.168.1.21 is wrong, it should stick to the server IP but how can I route it properly ?

Edit I : iptables is off on the virtual server

Edit II : I added the pasv_min_port/pasv_max_port to vsftpd.conf and it works for retrieving files list and open them... But I still can't upload anything

**Edit III : file transfer works fine when I force the rights permissions to 777 but it's clearly not a permanent solution**

Comment: What is the IP of the client you're connecting from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `pasv_address` vsftpd option to set the IP address that you want the server to advertise for passive data connections.